# How to solve Converting circular structure to JSON in node?

Tags: node.js

I was watching a course that showed how to make an console.log with custom configs, like the color or depending on your env mode, you show the log or not.

But i keep getting the error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
and I don't know why this is happening and how to solve it.

In the course, that works fine, but it doesn't to me.

node version => v8.11.2

```
require('colors')
const _ = require('lodash')

const config = require('../config/config')

const noop = () => { }

const consoleLog = config.logging ? console.log.bind(console) : noop

const logger = {
    log: () => {
        const args = _.toArray(arguments)
            .map(arg => {
                if (typeof arg === 'object') {
                    let str = JSON.stringify(arg, 2)
                    return str.magenta
                } else {
                    arg += ''
                    return arg.magenta
                }
            })
        consoleLog.apply(console, args)
    }
}

module.exports = logger
```

Edit1: `arguments` can be anything, since logger will be used to log things with different colors in the console.

`logger.log('some thing you want to log')`

Comment: Show us the structure of `arguments` please.

Comment: why the downvote? what is wrong with my question?

Comment: Vsemozhetbyt is right. Just wanted you to console.log arguments to verify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logger.log()` is an arrow function, so `arguments` are not arguments of this function (see [Arrow functions: No binding of `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments)), but arguments of a parent function, in this case — [Node.js wrapper function](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) that compiles modules and has arguments with circular dependencies.

Try to use common function here:

```js
const logger = {
  log() {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer and explanation

Comment: Just in case someone see this again, you can use `log(){}`or `log: function(){}` and it's the same